# What fields of a transaction are used when creating a transaction hash?

Tags: transactions

What fields does Ethereum use when creating a hash for a transaction? Suppose the following:

1. The blockchain has three blocks `block0` <- `block1` <- `block2`
2. There's a transaction `transaction2` which is originally in `block2` with hash `transactionHash2`
3. The blockchain gets reorged such that it's now `block0` <- `block3` <- `block4`
4. `transaction2` is now in `block4`

Would we expect that `transaction2` has the same hash now that it's in a different block with a different parent block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What fields does Ethereum use when creating a hash for a transaction?

There are a few transaction types supported by the network, therefore the fields needed to sign, serialize, and then generate the transaction hash vary.

Below are links to the go-ethereum repository where the different transaction types are defined (with their requisite fields/components):

- [LegacyTx](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/tx_legacy.go#L26-L34)
- [AccessListTx](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/tx_access_list.go#L46-L56)
- [DynamicFeeTx](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/tx_dynamic_fee.go#L25-L40)

> Would we expect that `transaction2` has the same hash now that it's in a different block with a different parent block?

Yes. The block a transaction is included in is independent of the transaction object itself. Before even submitting your signed transaction to the network, you can generate your transaction hash (the hash is a fingerprint of the transaction data).